# Regularized fit from summarized data

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I have a multiple linear regression problem $y=X\beta+\epsilon$. The number of observations $m$ is large, so by the time the data gets to me it's been summarized into:

- $m$
- $X^TX$
- $X^Ty$
- $y^Ty$
- $\sum_{i=1}^m{y_i}$

The above list appears sufficient to compute the OLS estimate. But can it be used to compute a regularized estimate of some sort (e.g. ridge regression)? If not, can the list be augmented in the same spirit to enable regularization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice to have in addition the covariance matrix of the residuals $\hat{\Sigma}$ to draw common inferences about the significance of estimated parameters, or if you are sure it is homoscedastic, then just $\hat{\sigma}^2$.

As for the regularizations of *generalised least squares* type (probably including instrumental variables estimators) the answer will be no. You need the original data matrices (though if you are supplied by $X^T \Omega^{-1}X$ and $X^T\Omega^{-1}y$ you may do GLS, but you loose the control for the choice of $\Omega$ anyway).

For general non-linear *[lasso](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf)* regularization it would be even more complicated. Luckily it may be approximated by ridge regression (see p. 273 in the reference) of a special type.

Regarding ordinary *ridge regression* it is sufficient, since all you need to do in this case is just to add elements to the diagonal $X^TX+\delta I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix. Thus in this particular case it works well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. It looks like ordinary ridge regression is the way to go for my application. I've posted a follow-on question about choosing a good value for $\delta$ (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/regularized-fit-from-summarized-data-choosing-the-parameter)