# Is there any optimization algorithms for these problems?

Tags: optimization

I have modeling the problem with the following equation:
$$
\min_{X} L(X)=f(X)-\alpha g(X) + \beta k(X)
$$
where $\alpha \gt 0, \beta \gt 0$, and, in my cases, I found the $f(X)-\alpha g(X) \lt 0$ and $k(X) \gt 0$, it seems this problem is not convex, how to set the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Is there any optimization algorithm for this problem? Is the Frank-Wolfe algorithm for solving these problems? Thanks!

Comment: What are the forms of $f(X)$, $g(X)$ and $k(X)$?

Comment: They are all convex functions. Specifically, $f(X)$ is within-class measure, $g(X)$ is between-class measure, $k(X)$ is a regularization term.

Comment: The sum of convex functions is convex. Do you worry for multiple local minima (for fixed $\alpha$, $\beta$)? Did a standard optimization procedure (eg. `L-BFGS-B`) failed? Smoothness maybe? This thread might give you some ideas about $\beta$:  [Regularized fit from summarized data: choosing the parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/regularized-fit-from-summarized-data-choosing-the-parameter)

Comment: Your function is a "difference of convex functions", for which there are specialized branch and bound algorithms.  If $X$ is quite small, then it might be reasonable to optimize this objective as a difference of convex functions.  If $X$ is large, then this is not likely to be practical.

Comment: Hi, @BrianBorchers, thank you for comments! $X$ is a matrix, and the $f(X)-\alpha g(X)$ has the same order of magnitude as $10^{13}$, and the $\beta k(x)$ has the same order of magnitude as $10^7$ or $10^8$. So it is difficult to select the parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters.

Comment: By "large", I was referring to the size of the matrix $X$.  Is it (e.g.) 10 by 10 or 1,000,000 by 1,000,000?

Comment: Hi, @usεr11852, thank you for your kindly references. I haven't used the gradient-based optimization for solving the problem. As you know, this is alike the linear discriminant analysis. The $k(X)$ is indeed a smoothness term. So I use the eigenvalue decomposition for solutions. But I found it is difficult to determine the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, sorry for my misunderstanding. The size of $X$ is less than $100 \times 100$. So the total size of all elements of $X$ is less than $10000$. This problem is alike the linear discriminant analysis, and I use it for dimension reduction. The $k(X)$ is defined as a smoothness term. So I use the eigenvalue decomposition for solutions.

Comment: Hi, @BrianBorchers, could you please give me some references about these optimization problems? Is it unpractical for solving these problems, thus few people have been modeling into these problems?

Comment: This is discussed for example in the recent book on Global Optimization by Locatelli and Schoen.  Your instances are large enough that this approach may not be practical.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, thank you very much for kindly suggestions! I don't know if people always want to avoid to model as these problems and how to determine its rationality. And with my very limited math, I think the evolutionary algorithms (e.g. NSGA-II) could be used for solving these problems. These problems seems to a continual combination optimization problem on the $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I don't know what are the practical solutions.

Comment: You might have more sucess with this Q over at our sister site https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks a lot for your kind suggestions.